# LEFT JOIN : display null for the right side

Tags: sql, join

Let's say we have 2 tables

```
TABLEA           TABLEB

1                 1   01/03/2022
2                 2   01/01/2022
3
```

This SQL statement:

```
select id 
from tableA 
left join tableB on tableA.id = tableB.id
```

displays:

```
1       1 01/03/2022
2       2 01/01/2022
3       NUll
```

Unfortunately, when I add a restriction on the right table, the behaviour is not the same.

```
select id   
from tableA 
left join tableB on tableA.id = tableB.id
where tableB.date > '01/01/2022'
```

I would like something like this :

```
1      1 01/03/2022
2      NULL
3      NULL
```

But I get this:

```
1      1 01/03/2022
```

That's all. I was not expecting this behavior. Can someone tell what the query should be ?

Comment: `NULL > '01/01/2022'` gives `NULL`, which is not truthy. Put the condition in the join, rather than the `WHERE`

Comment: why would that output be unexpected, you added a condition that has to be satisfied so the row will be in result, you are comparing a date to a null and that won't result in a satisfied condition, just add `or tableB.date is null` after `where tableB.date > '01/01/2022'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show data from table even if there is no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72206178/show-data-from-table-even-if-there-is-no-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 CREATE TABLE #TABLEA 
(
    ID tinyint
);

CREATE TABLE #TABLEB
(
    ID tinyint
    ,Date date
);

INSERT INTO #TABLEA
VALUES(1),(2),(3)

INSERT INTO #TABLEB
VALUES(1,'2022-03-01'),(2,'2022-01-01'),(3,NULL)


SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    #TABLEA t1
LEFT JOIN #TABLEB t2 ON t2.ID= t1.ID

AND t2.Date > '2022-01-01'

DROP TABLE
    #TABLEA
    ,#TABLEB;
```

When you added the WHERE clause you effectively changed the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN.  Putting the condition in the JOIN predicates keeps the LEFT JOIN as intended.